# Go to first line that doesn't begin with a certain string in vim

Tags: vim

Suppose I have the following buffer:

```
asdf
asdfotshne
asdfoensh
asdq
asdf
asdfothen
asdfghjkl;
qwertyuiop
zxcvbnm,.
```

Then I run `:v/^asdf/norm 0`.

I expect to have the cursor go to Line 4. But it doesn't, it goes to the end of the file.

Why?

Answer (score 9):

If your cursor is at first line of the file and you want to go to the first one that doesn't starts with `asdf`, you can use following `search` expression:

```
/\v^(asdf)@!
```

It does a negative look-ahead and stops in first match.

Answer (score 6):

`:v` is not used to move the cursor, but rather to perform an operation on all non-matching lines. As such, it scans every line of the file, and executes your `norm 0` on each one that does not start with asdf. It thus jumps at the first character of `qwertyuiop`, and then *does the same thing at `zxcvmnm,.`*.

It is easier to find the last *matching* line using `gg?`, then going one line down.

Answer (score 4):

Just to show that you can do this with `:v`.

```
:v/^asdf/throw ""
```

`:v` and `:g` will stop whenever an exception is thrown. You can do this with a throw, non-existent command, or an incomplete/malformed command.

```
:v/^asdf/^
```